# Storage System overflow control problem FTB mindcrack 1.4.7

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I have made a simple storage system in Minecraft FTB Mindcrack 1.4.7 which will store the main items from my quarry into chests (iron, diamond, tin, copper, etc.) and has an overflow section for other things:

Overflow area:

[image: Overflow]

The problem is that the items here go into a random chest and I can't control the flow using diamond pipes because there are to many types of items. Is there a way I can use pipes to control the items in a way they will enter the first chest containing the same item?

Comment: My suggestion would be to also sort the abundant but relatively useless stuff like stone, dirt, and gravel (or flint if your quarry produces that instead) since you'll be getting chests full of the stuff anyway,  Anything that's more rare but not considered very useful can all go into the overflow chest.

Comment: @MBraedley that's what i'm doing. The problem is that items just go all over the place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself after some research on a mod I am fairly new with. I used redpower 2.

[image: Storage]

what I did here is i made the end of my storage system run in to the chest from whitch it gets sucked out of by the filter and then gets send to the chests. this way they fill up one by one.

this system works because I have made a route trough the diamond pipes you see on the right (The main storage system.) using glass panes renamed "Barry". hoping I will never have to deal with an glass pane actually called that way.

The filter is controled with a timer to make it go off every second. on the structure pipe I have put an iron or gate which has it set to `inventory empty`--`edmit redstone signal`.

this way the chest closest to the filter will fill up first. then the second closest and so on.